# Are there a way to scan Android smartphone from outside the phone?

Tags: lock-screens, malware, antivirus

My friend's phone got a virus that he can't open his lock screen(every time he wants to do that, it says try 60minutes later again!).
So I am looking for a way like online virus scanner or any other ways to kill this virus?

Comment: It doesn't sound like a virus, it seems more like he's putting in the wrong code

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the device, hopefully it should work. If not, then try doing hard reset by clearing emmc cache. To hard reset the device press the volume down and power button at once - this works on most devices.

Comment: A factory reset already wipes the cache.